# Updated to 1.28 and now my Media Link HD won't connect?

Tags: htc-one-x

I got an HTC Media Link HD free with my phone for pre-ordering and it works fine, however having updated to the 1.28 software over the weekend, I found that I can no longer connect to the media link.

Is anyone aware of this issue or knows a way to fix it, as there seems to be very little detail about it online.

Comment: This has been escalated to the 'Escalations team' so might get a response from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an update from HTC Tech Support on this one.

**TL;DR**
Search for a software update and you should hopefully find 1.29. Once this is installed you'll be able to connect again fine.

**Quoted below**

> Dear David,
>
> Thank you for your patience.
>
> I would recommend backing up your data and performing a factory reset,
>   to do this please follow these steps:
>
> - If your phone is tied to a Google account, your contacts, calendar events, downloaded apps, wireless settings can be backed up, if you
>     have entered your Google account details in the initial set-up
>     screens. Please go to , Menu, Settings, Accounts & Sync, tap on your
>     Google account, then tap 'Sync now' you will see some spinning
>     circular arrows for a short while, this just means your data is being
>     saved to Google. When the arrows have finished spinning, the data has
>     been backed-up (double check this).
> - Or back up your contacts to the S.D card (For Android 2.1 or later) by following these steps; From the home screen tap All Applications. 
>     Scroll to and tap People.  Tap Menu.  Tap Import/Export.  Tap Export
>     to SD card.  Select which contact Group to export (Phone, Google, SIM
>     etc.).  Tap OK.
> - Available from the android market is a free application to enable you to back up your SMS messages if desired.
>
> Now your phone is backed up we can perform the hard reset, all data
>   will be lost that is not backed up on your S.D/SIM cards or online
>   will be lost.
>
> - Hard reset on Android From the Home screen, press the Menu key> Tap Settings> Tap SD & phone storage> Tap Factory data reset> Tap Reset
>     phone.
>
> The reason I have asked you to do this is because though it may seem a
>   bit extreme this is the best method for dealing with your problem.
>
> Once this has been done please manually search for an update.

I didn't actually do the reset, I simply searched for software updates and found the new update, installed it and all was well. I'd recommend this first before you wipe your phone!